# JavaScript unable to verify empty value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of google map markers and I'm removing some of them using the delete method.
The function I use is as below;

```
function removeMarker(markerOrder) {
   markers[markerOrder].setMap(null);
   delete markers[markerOrder];
   console.log(markers);
   counter--;
}
```

I cannot change delete as function because I need to keep the markers array order.

If I delete a value, in the console it is shown as replaced with empty as value.

So when all the markers are deleted from he markers array, I see in the console:

```
(4) [empty × 4]
```

I'm trying to verify if the array has all its values empty but it seems like the empty I see in console is neither null, "" nor undefined.

Here is my code:

```
function allEmpty(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       if (arr[i] !== null) {//Not working
       //if (arr[i].length !== 0) {//Not working
       //if (typeof(arr[i]) !== 'undefinded') {//Not working
       //if (arr[i] !== '') {//Not working
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Any help please?
Thanks.

Comment: They should be `undefined`, it looks like you might have spelled it `undefinded` in your `allEmpty()` function

Comment: If you want to keep the order just set that element to `null` instead of trying to delete it, eg `markers[markerOrder]=null`. Or just use a regular object

Comment: ill see myself out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the array is empty, you can use .some to help you, for example:

```
function allEmpty(arr) {
    return !arr.some(el=>el)
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, null, 6]
console.log(allEmpty(arr))
//false

const arr2 = ['', null, undefined]
console.log(allEmpty(arr2))
//true
```

Comment: `allEmpty()` will return `true` if all the elements are `0` or empty strings.

Comment: @Barmar But it is what he wants, right?

Comment: This will work if valid entries are objects, not more generally.

Comment: The argument is an array, as the user asked.

Comment: I'm talking about the array elements, not the argument.

Comment: code shares by @ElsonRamos works well, thanks.

Comment: To protect against `null`: `const allEmpty = (arr) => !arr || !arr.some(el => el)`

Answer (score 0):

`delete` sets the element to `undefined`, not `null`. So use that comparison in your loop.

```
function allEmpty(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       if (arr[i] !== undefined) {
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

You can also use the `every()` method:

```
function allEmpty(arr) {
    return arr.every(el => el === undefined);
}
```